# Why do I need to click twice on DataGrid to update my Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

Can anyone tell me why I need to click twice the first time I enter a new DataGrid in order for my Label to update it's Content?  I tried to cut out as much unneeded code as possible.

Here is my XAML

```
<Window x:Class="PSS.LateOrderPredictor.Ui.View.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:PSS.LateOrderPredictor.Ui.ViewModel"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="1350
    " WindowState="Maximized">
<Window.Resources>
    ...
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:SoSummaryViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="800"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="500"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SummaryLineItems}" 
             SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedSalesOrderViewModel, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             ...
             >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Expander HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          MaxHeight="500">
                    <Expander.Header>
                        ...
                    </Expander.Header>
                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LineItems}" 
                              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedDemandEvent,     UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          ...
                          />                        
                      </Expander>
                  </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Label Grid.Column="2"
           Grid.Row="0"
           <!--Here is the label I am trying to set-->
           DataContext="{Binding Path=SelectedSalesOrderViewModel, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
           Content="{Binding SelectedDemandEvent.PartNumber}"/>
           ...
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The `SelectedSalesOrderViewModel` is set when I click on the `DataGridRow` and is contained in my `SoSummaryViewModel` class.  It is getting set on the first click any time I click into a new `DataGrid`.

```
public class SoSummaryViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    ...
    /// <summary>
    /// The view model for the grid that contains the SelectedSalesOrderLine
    /// </summary>
    public SoSummaryLineViewModel SelectedSalesOrderViewModel
    {
        get { return _selectedSalesOrderViewModel; }
        set 
        {
            if (_selectedSalesOrderViewModel != value)
            {
                _selectedSalesOrderViewModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedSalesOrderViewModel");
            }
        }
    }      
}
```

After my initial two clicks (just needs to be two clicks, not an actual double-click event), the label will update any time the selected row is changed, as long as I stay within the same `DataGrid`.  I am using Expanders with a `DataGrid` inside, the Expanders are inside a `ListBox`.  Here is a picture, this may make it more clear.
[image]

Comment: I fail to see `DataGrid` in given `xaml`.

Comment: @Sinatr sorry, try looking now - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I wouldn't do this

```
if (_selectedSalesOrderViewModel != value)
    ...
```

And you need two clicks because your first click doesn't change selection in `DataGrid` (I assume). Moreover, it will work very strangely if you have 2 items expanded (is it possible?) as there will be two `DataGrids` bound to same item; if one has 10 items and 10th is selected, then how should second, with only 5 items handle that?

Try to use `OneWay` binding for `Label` and `OneWayToSource` for `DataGrid`.

P.S.: I am not sure if this is the right answer, but that would be too much for comment.